Two numbers written on a board get replaced
Question: "Several (at least two) nonzero numbers are written on a board. One
may erase any two numbers, say $a$ and $b$, and then write the numbers
$a+\frac{b}{2}$
and $b−\frac{a}{2}$
instead. Prove that the set of numbers on the board,
after any number of the preceding operations, cannot coincide with
the initial set."
What I tried: I tried looking at the smallest case of two numbers and use the sum before and after the operation to prove whether the numbers will coincide with the original set. So I get that the sum after will be $(a+b)+\frac{b-a}{2}$ and the sum initially to be $a+b$ and they are not equal if $a\neq b$, but $a$ and $b$ are not necessarily distinct and I don't now how to prove for any number of numbers written on a board. The solution uses the sum of squares instead of sums, but I don't know what's the difference, why that works instead of just using sums.

If the sum of squares always increases, then you will never reach the same set of numbers.

I posted another question taking this one as motivation: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4945313/growth-in-sum-of-squares-under-random-applications-of-a-b-to-ab-2-b-a-2-t

The problem with considering the sum, is that this can either increase or decrease with each turn.
If $a<b$, then the sum increases. If $a>b$, then the sum decreases. And so it is unclear whether we can return to the initial set.
If we instead consider the sum of squares, we see that it is increasing (although not necessarily strictly). And this shows we can never return to the initial set.
$$ \left(a+ \frac{b}{2}\right) ^2 + \left( b - \frac{a}{2} \right) ^2 = a^2 + ab + \frac{b^2}4 + b^2 - ab + \frac{a^2}{4}$$
$$=a^2 + b^2 + \frac{a^2 + b^2}{4} $$
$$\ge a^2 + b^2$$
EDIT:
We still require a way to break the equality here. As noted by @John Omielan, we can simply observe that the initial board contains only non-zero numbers and so the sum of squares must increase on (at least) the first turn.

Welcome to Math SE. This is a good answer, but IMHO it's a bit incomplete. Your $a^2+b^2+\frac{a^2+b^2}{4}\gt a^2+b^2$ isn't true if $a=b=0$. There's at least $2$ ways to handle this. First, if $a=b=0$, then $a+\frac{b}{2}=b-\frac{a}{2}=0$, so we're not actually changing anything. Thus, the set continues having at least $2$ zero values, which cannot match the initial set as it has no zero values. The second way is to replace $\gt$ with $\ge$, & note the first set of replacements are with $a\neq 0$ & $b\neq 0$, so the sum of squares has increased. Later sums continue to be larger than initial.

Good point, this was lazy on my part. Answer edited.

A friendly reminder that if you feel like your question has been sufficiently answered, you can accept an answer. This awards a green tick to let other users know the answer has been accepted and awards reputation to the author which helps incentivize further contributions.
