Growth in sum-of-squares under random applications of $(a,b)\to (a+b/2,b-a/2)$ to $\{1\}^N$
A recent question considered the following problem: "Several (at least two) nonzero numbers are written on a board. One
may erase any two numbers, say $a$ and $b$, and then write the numbers
$a+\frac{b}{2}$ and $b−\frac{a}{2}$ instead. Prove that the set of numbers on the board,
after any number of the preceding operations, cannot coincide with the initial set."
As noted by the answer, the resolution is that the sum of squares for $a,b$ transforms as
$$a^2+b^2\mapsto (a+b/2)^2+(b-a/2)^2=\frac54(a^2+b^2)$$
Since the rest of the set remains unchanged, the sum of squares of the entire set must increase by $\frac14(a^2+b^2)$ on each step. Hence the set of numbers can never return to its original state.
I'd like to transform this into a statistical question. Suppose the board begins with $N$ copies of $1$. We then randomly pick pairs of numbers on the board, updating each time. After $n$ such updates, what is the expected sum-of-squares?
To explore this numerically, I randomly generated evolutions of $N=20$ copies of 1 over a total of $n=1000$ steps. The log-plot (of sum-of-squares as a function of number of steps taken) below shows the result of 10 such evolutions:

This seems loosely reminiscent of a biased random walk, with the average sum-of-squares seeming to grow exponentially with $n$. A numerical fit in this particular case gives roughly $3e^{0.025n}$ for the average sum-of-squares. Can this growth be analyzed more precisely?

You could also ask about the distribution of the set. It seems to be approximately normal after many steps.

@JairTaylor True. Given how simple the expected value ended up, maybe I'll post another follow-up.

Suppose that, at some point, there are $N$ numbers $a_1,\ldots,a_N$ on the board. The sum of squares is currently $s_0:=a_1^2+\cdots+a_N^2$, and the new sum of squares is
$$s_0+\frac14(a_i^2+a_j^2),$$
where the pair $\{i,j\}$ is chosen uniformly at random from all unordered pairs of numbers in $\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$. As a result, the expected value of the new sum is
$$s_0+\frac14\left(\mathbb E[a_i^2]+\mathbb E[a_j^2]\right)=s_0+\frac{\mathbb E[a_i^2]}2=s_0+\frac{s_0}{2N}=\left(1+\frac1{2N}\right)s_0.$$
So, the expected sum of squares goes up by a factor of $1+\frac1{2N}$, regardless of what the numbers were. This means that, after $n$ steps, starting from $N$ ones, the expected sum of squares is
$$N\left(1+\frac1{2N}\right)^n.$$
(The growth rate of approximately $e^{0.025n}$ comes from the approximation $e^x\approx 1+x$, since $0.025=1/40$.)

Another minor point of interest here would seem to be to hold $r=n/N$ fixed, since then as $N\to\infty$ one has $N(1+1/(2N))^{r N}\sim Ne^{r/2}$.
